# Even and odd functions, can someone help me understand this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, symmetry

Functions $f$, $g$, and $h$ are defined as follows:
\begin{align}
f&: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, &f(x) &= x^2 - 10x + 9 \\ 
g&: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, &g(x) &= x^4 - 10x^2 + 9 \\ 
f&: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, &f(x) &= x^3 - 4x 
\end{align}

For each of these functions:

> a) Determine intersection points between the graph of the function and
> coordinate axes.
>
> b) Sketch the graph of the function. Is the graph symmetric about some
> straight line or at some point?
>
> c) Determine whether the function is even, odd, or neither even nor
> odd.

a) For $f$, we have $f(x) = x^2 - 10x + 9$. By setting $f(x) = 0$ and solving for $x$ we get $x = 1$ and $x = 9$. So the intersection points are $(1, 0)$ and $(9, 0)$?

For $g$, we have $g(x) = x^4 − 10x^2 + 9$. For $h$, we have $h(x) = x^3 − 4x$.

I know we've to set them equal to $0$ and solve for $x$ to find intersection points, but I have trouble completing the square and would need your help.

Not there yet with b).

I know that odd means $f(-x) = -f(x)$, and even means $f(-x) = f(x)$, for all $x$. Not quite sure what it means for it to be neither.

Comment: "Most" functions are neither even nor odd. If $g(x) = x^2+x$, then $g(-x) = x^2-x$, which is not the same function as $g(x)$ and not the same function as $-g(x)$.

Comment: You've done the more difficult part of finding $x$-intercepts, i.e. $x$-values where the graph of the function satisfies $y = 0$. However, you should also find the $y$-intercept, i.e. the $y$-value where $x = 0$. This is more straightforward, since you just have to evaluate the function.

Comment: Being "neither" means exactly that; it's neither.  It's fairly unusual for a function to be odd; that would mean $f(-x) =-f(x)$ for *every single possible value of* $x$.  And it's fairly unusual for a function to be even.  That would mean $f(-x) = f(x)$ for *every single possible value of* $x$.  More likely it is neither.  Take for instance $f(x)=x^3-x^2 + 1$.  Notice if we take a value, say $x=4$ we get $f(4)=49$.  So what is $f(-4)$ going to be? Well, will it be $f(-4)=-49$ or will it be $f(-4)=49$? Well, why on earth should it be either of those!?  $f(-4)=-79$.  It's neither odd nor even.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^2-10x+9$.  What is $f(-x)$?  $f(-x) = (-x)^2 -10\cdot(-x) + 9 = x^2+10x +9$.  Is that that same thing as $f(x)=x^2-10x + 9$?  No, it is not.  So $f$ is not even.  Is that the same thing as $-f(x) =-(x^2 -10x +9) =-x^2 +10x -9$?  No, it is not.  So $f$ is not odd.  So $f$ is not even and $f$ is not odd.  It is neither.

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses the symmetry properties of certain graphs and the notions of even and odd functions. First of all, the property of the graph of a function having a symmetry (either mirror reflection or rotation/origin reflection) is rare. Most functions have neither.

**Even function.** Geometrically speaking, the graph of an even function has mirror symmetry about the $y$-axis, i.e. $(x, y)$ is on the graph if and only if $(-x, y)$ is on the graph. But that means that $f(-x) = y = f(x)$, which is the algebraic condition you mention at the bottom.

The graph of $f$ that you're working with is a parabola (since it's a quadratic polynomial function), and you probably know that parabolas have a reflection symmetry, but in this case, the axis of symmetry is the vertical line $x = 5$ (the average of the roots). As we can work out, this means that $f(5-x) = f(5+x)$ for all $x$, but that symmetry doesn't have a name like *even*. You can even see this by completing the square in $x$. (Try it yourself before revealing the spoiler.

> $$f(x) = x^2 - 10x + 9 = x^2 - 10x + 25 - 16 = (x - 5)^2 - 16 $$

You can shift to a new horizontal coordinate, say $X = x - 5$, so $x = X + 5$ and work out what $f(X)$ is:

> $$f(X) = f(x - 5) = (x - 5)^2 - 16 = X^2 - 16, $$

and in this form, it's easy to see that $f(X) = f(-X)$ for all $X$, it has symmetry about the vertical line $X = 0$. Translating this back into the original horizontal coordinate $x$, we see that $f(5-x) = f(5+x)$ and that the vertical line $x = 5$ is the axis of symmetry of the parabola.

You can probably work out that your function $g$ is in fact even. (It turns out that for *polynomial* functions, being even means having only nonzero terms of even degree, and the quartic polynomial $g$ has terms of degrees $4$, $2$, and $0$.) This general observation about polynomials also demonstrates why $f$ is *not even* since it has a nonzero linear term, i.e. a term of odd degree.

**Odd function.** Geometrically speaking, the graph of an odd function has mirror symmetry about the origin, i.e. $(x, y)$ is on the graph if and only if $(-x, -y)$ is on the graph. But that means that $f(-x) = -y = -f(x)$, which is the algebraic condition you mention at the bottom. By the way, this is equivalent to the symmetry whereby we take the graph and rotate it half-way around $(180^\circ)$ about the origin, but that's not necessary here.

You can verify that your function $h$ satisfies this property by evaluating at an arbitrary $-x$ expression and simplifying it to match the value at $x$:

> $$h(-x) = (-x)^3 - 4(-x) = -x^3 + 4x = -(x^3 - 4x) = -h(x) $$

One property that all such odd functions follows immediately from the fact that $-0 = 0$ so $h(0) = h(-0) = -h(0)$. But what number equals its opposite? Only zero. Hence, $h(0) = 0$, i.e. assuming that the function is defined at $0$, the graph passes through the origin, the center of the $180^\circ$ rotation.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is $f(x^2)$, so the intersection points of $g$ with the $x$ axis are the square roots of the intersection points of $f$ with the $x$ axis.

For $h$ it's clear that $h(0)=0$ so you have one intersection point. Then you can write $h(x)=x(x^2-4)$ and you might be able to guess the other two intersection points.

Most functions aren't either odd or even. For example $\sin(x)$ is odd, and $\cos(x)$ is even, but any sum of $\sin$ and $\cos$ is neither even nor odd.